# Can i chant the Ashtottara nama of Maa Lakshmi for better finanacial situation?

Tags: vishnu, gods, devi, lakshmi, ashtottara-shatanamavali

my family's financial condition has been quite bad since a very long time(10+ years), we are in huge debts and are in a hand to mouth situation living by just by the grace of god. can i chant the 108 names of Maa Lakshmi to benefit a bit financially? and i searched the names on the internet but i wanted to make sure they're non-tantrik or do not contain any rahasaya naams, since i am uniniated hence i cant do those. if possible could you share the non tantrik ones? thank you all, i appreciate your help...

Comment: Yes you can chant .. do not worry about if the names from Puranas or Tantras. There are many websites from where you can find the Ashtottara stotras.

Answer (score 1):

Most sadhakas dismay Artha, but to to grihastha dharmanirvaaha, devapitrukarya, etc one needs wealth. Thus there's nothing wrong in seeking for Artha, till the time it is earned by dharma and used for dharma.

```
but i wanted to make sure they're non-tantrik or do not contain any rahasaya naams
```

Asnwering main question here, the Ashtotram available online are mostly from Laxmi tantra. But since you want to avoid tantric stotrams, then rather go for Ashtotram from Narada upapurana.

The Phalashruti says,

> श्रियं वर्चसमारोग्यं शोभनं धान्यसम्पदः ।
> पशूनां बहुपुत्राणां लाभश्च सम्भावेद्ध्रुवम् ॥
> With the blessings of Srì one shall get health, grains, wealth, animals, and with be benefitted with birth of alot sons.

```
if possible could you share the non tantrik ones?
```

Well, I have even jotted a few additional stotras too with fhalashruti (to boost faith in stotra),

Laxminarayan samhita Shree Laxmi namavali,

> ऐतानि लक्ष्मीनामानि सदा प्रातः पठेध्दियः ।
> स पुत्रपौत्रादियुक्तः श्रियमाप्नोत्यनाशिनीम् ||
> One who reads these names of Laxmi daily at dawn, with be benefitted with Sons, grandsons, and along those with his Srì (wealth) shall be indestructible.

Agastyamunikrutha Laxmi stotram,

> यः पठेत्प्रातरुत्थाय श्रद्धा-भक्तिसमन्वितः ।
> गृहे तस्य सदा स्थास्ये नित्यं श्रीपतिना सह ॥
> सुखसौभाग्यसम्पन्नो मनस्वी बुद्धिमान् भवेत् ।
> पुत्रवान् गुणवान् श्रेष्ठो भोगभोक्ता च मानवः ||
> If one reads this at dawn after waking with faith and devotion, in his house Srì along with her consort Srì pati (Vishnu) will be stationed permanently. He shall be blessed by happiness, fortune, and become intellectual. Will have sons, himself be a great virtuous man, and will enjoy all materialistic joy.

Devi bhagwatam, Indrakruta Laxmi stotram,

> इदं स्तोत्रं महापुण्यं त्रिसन्ध्यं यः पठेन्न्रः ।
> कुबेरतुल्यः स भवेत् राजराजेश्वरो महान् ॥
> If one reads this stotram in three sandhyas (dawn, afternoon, dusk) shall himself become like Kubera (wealthy) and thus become a great emperor.

Padma Puran, Indrakruta Mahalaxmi stotram,

> एककाले पठेन्नित्यं महापापविनाशनं ।
> द्विकालं यः पठेन्नित्यं धनधान्य समन्वितः ॥
> त्रिकालं यः पठेन्नित्यं महाशत्रूविनाशनं ।
> महालक्ष्मीर्भवेन्नित्यं प्रसन्ना वरदा शुभा ||
> Those who chant this once will get rid of sins, those who read this twice will be blessed with wealth and grains. Who who reads thrice will be blessed with destruction of enemies (internal & external) and Mahalaxmi will always be pleased thus giving thr best boons.

```
we are in huge debts
```

I would say stick to one stotra, but since you have debts you must chant Rinmochana Ganapati Stotram, aided with any of the aforementioned stotrams.
Even Kanakadhara Stuti by Bhagwadpada helps.

Not just these, there are stotras of Ganapati, Nataraja, Chandika, Narayana, Shiva, etc deities too, to give artha. All it takes is, a stout faith in your ishta devta. Do any stotram but with whole devout, the results would ripe sooner.

*But, would like to add a short disclaimer, once Srì favours the person, let not the greed bite the person. Donate a fraction of wealth timely for devta, pitru, sadhu and jeeva seva. That way the wealth not only increases manifold times, but also gives the merits thus taking one near real goal of Moksha*

**श्रीकालिकार्पणमस्तु |**